# Выражение "в этой связи"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Допустимо ли выражение "в этой связи"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, это просторечное выражение и в русском языке не допустимо как неграмотное. Первым этот оборот ввел в официальную речь М.С. Горбачев, за которым уже начали повторять остальные (как, в свое время, все повторяли за Н.С. Хрущевым "коммунизЬм", "сосисЬка" и т.д.).
Правильно говорить "В связи с этим".

Comment: Ну, вряд ли Горбачев придумал этот оборот. Разве что сделал его более заметным.

Answer (score 3):

Соответствуя норме современного русского литературного языка, это устойчивое cочетание "*в этой связи*" употребляется как наречие со значением '*связывая со сказанным выше*' и служит своеобразной формулой перехода от одной мысли к другой. Словосочетание *в этой связи*, выступая в предложении в значении наречия со значением '*связывая со сказанным выше*', в "Большом толковом словаре русского языка" под ред. С. А. Кузнецова (СПб., 2000, с. 1164) зафиксировано без каких-либо ограничительных стилистических помет.
Но употребление сочетания *в этой связи* не рекомендуется вместо сочетания *в связи с этим*, т. к. последнее выполняет в предложении иную функцию, а именно выражает причинную связь между частями высказывания. 
Т. е. употребление слов *в этой связи* ошибочно для тех случаев, где налицо конкретное отношение причинности.

Например: Наступает весна. В этой связи вспоминается такой случай из жизни... - корректно. 
Но: Наступает весна. В связи с этим (не в этой связи!) проблема уборки дворовых территорий становится еще более актуальной. 
Важно иметь в виду, что выражение в этой связи характерно прежде всего для публицистики.

Answer (score 1):

Именно в том смысле, в котором Вы скорее всего подразумевали - мне это выражение не нравится и я соглашусь с **Max**.

С другой стороны, вполне возможно грамотное употребление данного набора слов: "В этой связи нет ничего предосудительного." (если речь идет про любовную связь между людьми) Поэтому сказать, что вот давайте возьмем и вообще не будем употреблять эти слова нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос [сдублировался](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8)

(а модераторы, как я понял,  скептически относятся к закрытию вопросов пользователями в подобных случаях).

Поэтому передаю тезисно.

1. Речь идёт об использовании выражения "в этой связИ" вместо "в связи с этим", "в связи с вышеизложенным", при этом подразумевается некая причинно-следственная или логическая связь. Такое использование признается некорректным. Иные случаи правомочны и сомнений обычно не вызывают. Тем более не обсуждается нормативность конструкции "в этой свЯзи", когда речь идёт именно о связях, включая любовные и порочащие.
2. В значении "связывая со сказанным выше" (хотя даже сам по себе такой оборот сомнителен стилистически) использование возможно, и допускаю, что он есть в словарях (сам не видел). Но беда-то в том, что чаще всего этот оборот используют в другом контексте, фактически заменяя "кстати", "в дополнение к сказанному" и проч. Последние случаи, насколько понимаю, никакими словарями не регламентируются.