# "В этой связи"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли в русском языке оборот "в этой связИ" или это бездумное повторение за Горбачевым, который, кажется, первым его употребил? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынужден указать на ошибочность опубликованных ответов. Оба варианта корректны. Первый – *в связи с этим* – характерен прежде всего для текстов официально-делового стиля (но, конечно, далеко не только для них). Второй – *в этой связи* – для текстов публицистических. Что, как вы понимаете, недвусмысленно свидетельствует о **литературности** (не просторечности!) этого сочетания. Мих. Серг. далеко не изобретатель его: оно фиксировалось словарями и в 60-е, и в 70-е. См. в этой связи (смайлик) «Правильность русской речи» С.И. Ожегова 1965 года или, скажем, «Трудности словоупотребления и варианты норм русского литературного языка» К.С. Горбачевича 1974 г. Как видно из моего примера, сочетание это употребляется как наречие с семантикой 'связывая со сказанным выше' и выпоняет функции текстовой скрепы.

Comment: Ожегов и Горбачевич - это, конечно, авторитеты, но их в сети нет.
Можно какую-нибудь внятную цитатку из указанных источников?

Или хотя бы пример бесспорный пример правильного употребления *в этой связи* хотя бы из публицистики? А то создаётся впечатления, что мы о разных случаях говорим. Беда в том, что аскер контекст не даёт.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нет.
Или "в связИ с этим", или уж "в этой свЯзи".

Answer (score 0):

Только "в связИ с этим"

Comment: Не только. *Штирлиц имел связь с Мюллером. В **этой свЯзи** не было ничего порочащего.*

Comment: В данном случае это существительное "связь" в предложном падеже.

Comment: Штирлиц знал, что это существительное в предложном падеже, он не знал, *в какой связи* он об этом должен вспомнить.

Comment: Наверное, в тесной...

Comment: Инна, но помилуйте, автор ведь не спрашивает, существительное оно или это или ещё какое. Вопрос стоит о возможности употребления без каких бы то ни было оговорок.  
Кстати, воспользуюсь случаем сообщить всем, что я посмотрел немного по сети - убедительных примеров употребления "в этой связИ" так и не обнаружил.

Answer (score 0):

В английском языке определенный артикль the разрешается употреблять тогда, когда ранее уже шла речь об этом предмете, например: To support my opinion I can tell you about very intresting case. **THE** case was considered... Точно такая же аналогия и в русском (и, по здравому смыслу, должна быть и в любом другом) языке: слова ЭТОТ, ЭТА подразумевают ссылку на то, что раньше уже упоминалось или обсуждалось, например: в ЭТОМ есть свой резон. Невозможно понять смысл этой фразы, не зная, о чем шла речь до нее. Поэтому, если мы ***сначала рассуждали о связи*** между известными персонами (Штирлиц и Мюллер), описали связь между физическими явлениями, или связь между питанием и здоровьем,и т. д., мы только тогда можем сказать "в ЭТОЙ связи" (Например: в ЭТОЙ свЯзи еще много загадочного). Если ранее ни о какой СВЯЗИ между чем-то и чем-то не говорилось, то говорить "в ЭТОЙ связи" недопустимо; для ссылки на нечто, сказанное ранее, необходимо пользоваться конструкцией "в связи с этим". Пусть обсуждалась связь питания и здоровья. Диктор: "В этой связи много непонятного. В этой связи мы пригласили эксперта..." - на самом деле, не в связи со связью, а **В СВЯЗИ С ЭТИМ** пригласили эксперта (тем, что много непонятного). Еще раз: "в этой связи" - отсылает к связи, "В связи с этим" - отсылает к любой ситуации, высказыванию, явлению, упомянутым ранее.

Comment: Очень много слов, а вопроса-то Вы, боюсь, не поняли. Значение слова "этот", надеюсь, тут и так все прекрасно понимают. Но спрашивают-то не о том куда отсылают, а о том, насколько правомерно использование "в этой связи" вместо "в связи с этим". И тут никакие артикли не помогут.

Comment: Я пояснил, когда допустима конструкция "в этой связи". Использование ее вместо "в связи с этим" - недопустимо.

Comment: Из вашего текста это совершенно непонятно. Английский-то зачем пристегнули?  Неужели без этого значение слова "этот" на русском непонятно?

Answer (score 0):

А я впервые услышал эту конструкцию в выступлении Л. И. Брежнева.