# Ставятся ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в следующем предложении?

> В этой связи для получения более подробной информации касательно
>   получения займа Вам необходимо обратиться в Управление.

Comment: Многовато "получений" для одного предложения.

Comment: Первое «получение» надо убрать: «В этой связи за более подробной информацией касательно получения займа вам необходимо обратиться в Управление». Со вторым — всё нормально. («Сумма за оформление заявки на получение займа».)

Answer (score 2):

***Для получения более подробной информации относительно  выдачи займа Вам необходимо обратиться в Управление.***

Пояснение

1) Весьма вероятно, что сочетание ***в этой связи*** здесь лишнее, так как это предложение выглядит вполне самостоятельным  (для получения более подробной информации обычно не требуется  особых причин). С другой стороны,  для окончательного вывода нужен контекст.

В любом случае сочетания ***в связи с этим*** и ***в этой связи*** не обособляются.

**Вопрос № 255349.** Скажите пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после "в связи с этим" в этой фразе: В связи с этим, обращаемся к Вам с просьбой перезаключить имеющиеся договоры с новым юридическим лицом. Ответ справочной службы русского языка: **Запятая не ставится.**

2) В словаре есть оба выражения: ***в связи с этим*** и ***в этой связи***.

<В связи с кем-чем, **в зн. предлога.** Вследствие чего-л., по причине чего-л. Закрыть библиотеку в связи с ремонтом. Опоздали в связи с нарушением режима работы транспорта. **В связи с тем, чтобы, в зн. союза.** В целях того, чтобы. Провёл опрос в связи с тем, чтобы выяснить общественное мнение. **В связи с тем, что, в зн. союза.** По той причине, что, на основании того, что. Обдумывал положение в связи с тем, что собирался уехать. **В этой связи, в зн. нареч.**

3) На форуме обсуждался вопрос на тему сочетаний ***в связи с этим*** и ***в этой связи***. В одном из ответов объясняется разница в их значении.
 [Выражение "в этой связи"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/331/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8)

Примеры:

Кстати, объём накопленных иностранных инвестиций в экономике России составил на конец 2003 года 57 млрд. долларов. Не могу не отметить **в этой связи** рост интереса к российскому рынку со стороны латвийских банков.

Важное значение имеет для нас выполнение поставленной главами наших государств задачи превращения Каспийского региона в регион мира, дружбы и добрососедства. **В этой связи** особое внимание уделили задаче совместного противодействия терроризму...

Answer (score 0):

Нет, здесь запятые не нужны. Странно звучит " В этой связи". Имеется в виду " В связи с этим"? Если переставить части предложения местами,  то сразу видно что запятые не нужны.
"В связи с этим Вам необходимо обратиться в Управление для получения более подробной информации касательно получения займа."

Comment: Вы знаете, от перестановки частей "видимости" не добавляется. Впрочем, фраза вообще настолько косноязычна, что запятыми здесь не спасешься. Не находите?