# О предлогах касательно и относительно

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Предлоги ***касательно*** и ***относительно*** **в некоторых случаях** могут заменять друг друга, а вот в каких? И чем они тогда отличаются?

Если верить словарю, то предлог ***касательно*** используется в официальной и книжной речи, но так ли это? Конечно, слова-синонимы обычно стараются найти для себя свою область применения, но при этом ситуация может меняться со временем.

Вот, к примеру, Пушкин: *Лиза тихонько нарядилась крестьянкою, шёпотом дала Насте свои наставления **касательно мисс Жаксон**, вышла на заднее крыльцо и через огород побежала в поле.*

Здесь, конечно, никакой официальности нет.

А это современный текст: Недавние трагические события  вновь напомнили о том, что сегодня жертвой террористического нападения может стать любая страна. Они не оставляют никаких иллюзий **относительно** всё более полного сращивания международных и «местных» террористических сетей. // «Дипломатический вестник», 2004]

Здесь предлог ***относительно*** вполне на месте. И как мне кажется, область применения предлога ***касательно*** сужается,  **предлоги перестают заменять друг друга,** а стилистика ***касательно*** в этом случае представляется или уж очень официальной, или скорее просторечной, или иронической.

Как, например, в недавно рассмотренном примере: [Ставятся ли запятые?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/455935/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5)

**И вопрос:** Чем отличаются предлоги ***касательно*** и ***относительно*** в тех случаях, когда по смыслу они могут заменять друг друга?

**КАСАТЕЛЬНО,** предлог. кого-чего. Книжн. и офиц. **Относительно кого-, чего-л.** Быть осведомлённым к. всех обстоятельств дела.

**ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНО** II. предлог. кого-чего. По отношению к кому-, чему-л., **в отношении кого-, чего-л.** Симметрия геометрических фигур о. оси. Исполнить свой долг о. наследников. Не иметь определённых намерений о. кого-л.

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос. Разница между данными словами сопоставима с разницей между предлогами *о/про*.

"Относительно" сопоставимо с "о".

"Касательно" сопоставимо с "про".

Сравнить:

*Мнение правительства Украины относительно предложений Российской Федерации сводится к следующему.* || Можно заменить на "мнения о предложениях". "Про" и "касательно" здесь плохо подходят.

*Государства-члены провели откровенный обмен мнениями относительно круга ведения Консультативного комитета.* || Здесь то же самое.

*Конечно, никто не вправе требовать от меня как от рассказчика слишком точных подробностей касательно одного пункта.* || Подробности про один пункт - больше подходит. Соответственно "касательно" выигрывает у "относительно".

Не говорю, что разница абсолютно сопоставима, но данные закономерности часто прослеживаются.

Вывод:

"Касательно" направленно на конкретный предмет, объект, субъект (*касательно мисс Жаксон, касательно нашей роботы*).

"Относительно" чаще направлено на общие понятия (*относительно направлений, относительно деятельности*).

Данную разницу можно проследить и в самих значениях слов: *относясь к чему-то (можно напрямую относиться, можно косвенно; близкое отношение / далёкое отношение)*; *касаясь (конкретно касаясь чего-то)*.

"Касательно" распространено в официально-деловом стиле, так как там преобладает конкретика.

Когда они могут взаимозаменяться - когда по смыслу имеется в виду что-то конкретное, но тем не менее общее понятие. Но всё равно один из вариантов будет подходить больше.

Answer (score 1):

Чем отличаются предлоги *касательно* и *относительно* в тех случаях, когда по смыслу они могут заменять друг друга?

В отличие от *относиться*, указывающего на непременную дистанцию, у слова *касаться* две опции: первая, исключающая любую удалённость прямым точечным контактом (Его губ касался металлический край кружки), и вторая, умозрительная (Что касается смерти, то ощущать её мы не можем).

Сфера употребления обсуждаемых предлогов-синонимов — наряду с *насчет; об; по части; в отношении; в рассуждении; о* — практически одна. Не позволяет совсем уподобиться паре *касательно/относительно* вторая жизнь этих форм как наречий и прилагательных. Старое или просторечное ***касаемо*** более подходит предлогу ***относительно*** в качестве подмены.

Answer (score 1):

> Если верить словарю, то предлог касательно используется в официальной
>   и книжной речи, но так ли это?

Думаю, словарю надо верить. 
Слово касательно в в бытовой речи сильно устарело, подозреваю, что оно и при Пушкине держалось только за счет всеобщего владения французским.

Остальное представляется мне надуманным.

> И вопрос: Чем отличаются предлоги касательно и относительно в тех
>   случаях, когда по смыслу они могут заменять друг друга?

Думаю, что ничем кроме стиля. Хорошо бы конечно, конкретные примеры - в количестве достаточном для анализа. Я просто не вижу таких, где бы проявилась разница в значениях.

Answer (score 0):

**Спасибо всем, кто ответил на мой вопрос!**

Я попробую рассказать, как я понимаю эту тему.

1) Предлоги образованы от глаголов ***касаться*** и ***относиться***. Значение у глаголов разное: в прямом (пространственном)  смысле ***коснуться***  — это дотронуться. А вот значение глагола ***относиться*** весьма неопределенное: он может обозначать как  близкие, так и поверхностные отношения.

Поэтому мы можем сказать: ***Это тебя лично касается. Это всех касается/ ко всем относится.***

2) **Эту семантическую разницу сохраняют и предлоги**, но предлог ***касательно*** чаще употребляется в старых текстах. В современной же речи он выглядит несколько **архаично**, поэтому использовать его нужно обдуманно. В любом случае, его **стилистика не кажется нейтральной.**

3) **Вот у Л. Толстого:** *Теперь же тысячи новых, неясных мыслей, **касательно** одинокого положения их, зароились в моей голове, и мне стало так совестно, что мы богаты, а они бедны, что я покраснел и не мог решиться взглянуть на Катеньку.*

Сейчас мы скорее бы сказали так: *Теперь же тысячи новых, неясных мыслей, **касающихся** одинокого положения их...*  Предлог ***относительно*** здесь не лучшая замена, так как предмет нужно обозначить **более конкретно**, чем это можно сделать с помощью этого предлога.

**Вот еще пример:**  *Книгу написал Американский врач. Я даже сама там много полезного вычитала для себя ***касательно*** здоровья.*  [ Наши дети: Подростки (2004)]

Здесь предлог ***касательно***, как мне кажется, уместен **в разговорном стиле**.

4) Сам вопрос о предлогах у меня возник при ответе на вопрос [Ставятся ли запятые?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/455935/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5)

*В этой связи для получения более подробной информации **касательно** получения займа Вам необходимо обратиться в Управление.*

Это деловая речь, при этом более подробная информация скорее ***относится*** к теме, а не ***касается*** ее непосредственно, то есть не является основной. Поэтому стилистически нейтральный предлог ***относительно*** представляется здесь более уместным **и по значению, и по стилю**.